# WPF Window objects are blacked out on second screen in Windows 10

Tags: wpf, windows-10

Forgive me if this is a technical issue rather than a software-programming one, but I am having difficulty determining the probable cause here, be it the .NET Framework or something lower level, perhaps graphics hardware. Essentially, no WPF application will run on a second monitor using my Windows 10 Alienware 13 laptop. The same application, on the same monitor, running under my Windows 8 Alienware 15, will work fine. Visual Studio 2015 is a similar case, if there might be a common factor. Any experience with this sort of issue would be appreciated

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Easily reproduced in any WPF application that allows resizing and moving the screen to secondary monitor using winkey+arrows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the issue seems to be in the hardware acceleration in WPF applications, as disabling it made it impossible to reproduce the problem (which previously I had no trouble doing using winkey+arrows to move WPF from primary to secondary screen)

The following registry edit can be used to disable hardware acceleration inside WPF applications:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics]
"DisableHWAcceleration"=dword:00000001
```

Sources:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/963021

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx

Comment: Please note though, that I have been able to reproduce the problem on my machine using a Remote Desktop window as well (same symptoms and reproduction steps) ; so the actual problem is not in WPF, seemd to be an interplay between Windows 10 and the video driver.

Comment: Using these registry edits have had no effect for me (except making WPF slower). NVIDIA Quadro m3000m

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with my Windows 10 and dual monitor ( laptop screen + second monitor connected by HDMI ).

The solution in my case to fix the "black window in the second monitor" was this:

Locate your graphic-card vendor configuration interface by right clicking your desktop. In this pop-up menu you will find something like "Intel graphics" or "nVidia configuration", "AMD Control center", etc...

Find the "scaling options" and change the value. I disabled the "scaling" (OFF) and the problem was fixed, so this issue is related with the auto-scaling of the windows when you move your application between screens.

Please find these screenshots as example from my computer:
[image: Vendor menu]

[image: Scalling options]

Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/dual-monitor-different-resolutions-black-program/58ec488a-b62d-4ce8-a058-5e01e2a54d9a

Answer (score 1):

Disabling hardware acceleration for the application, worked for me. This can be executed at any point and works immediately. So you can call this when the wpf app is already running

`RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;`

[Microsoft manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.renderoptions.processrendermode?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: This worked for my system and is by far my preferred option.  Can easily allow the user to enable/disable hardware rendering based on their own experience and conditions.