# Transparent child window renders as black when screen sharing main window on Microsoft Teams

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, pinvoke, microsoft-teams

**Problem description**
I have a WPF child window and a WPF main window. The main window is set as the owner of the child window. The child window has a transparent background and is positioned on top of the main window.

When I share my entire screen, meeting guests can see the main window and child window and all content of both windows just fine.
When I share only the main window, meeting guests see the background of the child window as black instead of transparent.

On my own screen both windows render just fine - regardless of how they are shared.

The issue is reproducable on Microsoft Teams - but not on Zoom.

This is how the application renders on my computer - regardless of how I share my screen:
[image: Transparent window renders fine]

This is how meeting participants see the application when I share my entire screen (screenshot only illustrating application, but obviously the entire screen is visible to participants):
[image: Child window with transparent window renders fine on my computer]

This is how meeting participants see the application when I share only the main window (the black part is the background of the child window and it should really appear transparent and NOT black):
[image: Child window with transparent window renders with black background]

If I change the background of the child window to e.g. `Brushes.Green` instead of `Brushes.Transparent`, it renders correctly as seen by participants:
[image: Child window with green background renders fine]

So clearly there is an issue when transmitting the capture of a transparent child window.

**Technologies used**
C#, WPF, .NET Framework 4.8 (haven't tested if the same issue appears on other target frameworks, e.g. .NET Core, but changing the target framework is not an option).

**Minimal sample code that reproduces the issue**
`MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="600"
        Background="LightBlue"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid Height="500" Width="500" Background="CornflowerBlue" />
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ContentRendered += delegate { CreateChildWindow(); };
        }

        private void CreateChildWindow()
        {
            var childWindow = new Window
            {
                WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
                AllowsTransparency = true,
                Background = Brushes.Transparent,
                WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen,
                Height = 400,
                Width = 400,
                ShowInTaskbar = false,
                Content = new Grid {Background = Brushes.Red, Height = 100, Width = 100},
                Owner = this
            };

            childWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Constraints**

- In the real application, the main window is a 3rd party native Win32 application. The child window, however, lives in the same process space as the main window.
- The child window must appear with a transparent background and be able to have fully opaque content.
- I must use WPF/.NET for the child window. The WPF contents could potentially be hosted in a WinForms `Form` with an `ElementHost` or a raw `HwndSource` if that solves anything.
- I don't care if I have to use PInvoke, Windows hooks, etc. I use that extensively already.
- It could be acceptable to have the child window not appearing (as seen by participants) when screen sharing.

**Things I have tried to no avail**

- I have tried not making the main window the owner of the child window but that removes the nice behavior that you get with an owner relationship: e.g. child window is always on top of owner (without using `TopMost`), the child window minimizes, maximizes, restores and closes together with the main window. Also the child window doesn't appear at all when sharing the main window. This could be acceptable as a last resort, as I would rather not have the child window appear on the screen sharing session, than it appearing black.
- I have tried to PInvoke `SetWindowLong` using `GWL_HWNDPARENT` to set the owner relationship manually (I guess that is what `window.Owner` does). Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlonga#remarks
- I have tried to PInvoke `SetWindowLong` and clear the `WS_POPUP` and `WS_OVERLAPPED` flags and setting the `WS_CHILD`, then followed by a call to `SetParent` in order to create a 'visual' parent/child relationship instead of the logical owner relationship that `window.Owner` creates. This is specified in the documentation to `SetParent`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent#remarks . This actually solves the issue but instead creates visual glitches in other scenarios.
- I have tried to PInvoke `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` on the child window using `LWA_COLORKEY` and then setting the background of the child window to e.g. Magenta and then specify that color code as the transparent color key. This actually fixes the black background but the window renders without content and a weird border. I have read that this could happen because WPF is built on Direct3D and `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` is actually meant for windows rendered with GDI. According to this blog (however, quite old so may not reflect today's world) it may also be because `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` will put the window into a so-called 'System-Redirected Content mode', which is not supported by WPF https://dwayneneed.github.io/wpf/2008/09/08/transparent-windows-in-wpf.html
- I have tried to PInvoke `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` to set the child window display affinity to `WDA_MONITOR` and `WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE`. Excluding the child window from being captured could be a viable option for my purpose, however, Microsoft Teams seems to capture the window using methods that ignore this setting.
- I have tried to disable hardware acceleration by setting `RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly`.
- The issue is reproducable when sharing from different machines with different hardware.

To be frank, I'm a bit at a loss as to how to solve this. Probably primarily because I cannot understand why the issue is occuring in the first place. I have scoured the Internet and found no one with a similar issue. I hope that someone can shed a bit of light - if not on a solution, then at least on why the issue may be occuring.

Comment: Did you try anything like updating graphics drivers, or changing hardware acceleration settings? Maybe some of these suggestions could help, although the issue mentioned isn't really the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775917/wpf-window-objects-are-blacked-out-on-second-screen-in-windows-10

Comment: This is not really your fault, sort of. A process can have many windows, each one in its own corner (ie: move your window away from the red center and press ALT-TAB you will only see the blue rects). So, capturing a "process windows" means nothing. Capturing the whole screen always work because there's an API (DXGI desktop duplication). Even one window capturing depends on implementation (use OBS and you'll see the red block one capture is all broken). So it depends on Zoom and Teams implementation. In the end, it just means a multi-windows app cannot be shared easily.

Comment: For example this app: https://github.com/MathewSachin/Captura successfully captures the blue rects window with the red rect in the middle. It works of course as long as the red corner stays inside. If you move the blue rects window, the red corner moves and may get away. Again it depends on capturing app implementation. Maybe you could report that to Zoom and Teams so at least they work if windows overlap.

Comment: For issues related to teams product please reach out to [Product Support Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels)

Comment: Bassie, great idea! I just tried that without luck unfortunately. I also forgot to mention that the issue is reproducable on multiple machines with different hardware.

Simon Mourier, many thanks for investigating! Yes, clearly there is an issue with multiple windows - but I should add that a child window using a non-transparent background renders just fine (I updated the problem description to reflect this). So the issue is isolated to child windows using a transparent background.

VaraPrasad-MSFT, many thanks for your input! I will report an issue through official channels then.

Comment: I am having a very similar problem! Would definitely welcome any updates to this...

Comment: Smolakian, we went with the `SetWindowLong` approach described in bullet no. 3. Hope that helps somewhat. Also, we were in close contact with Microsoft support, who recognized the issue, but deemed it as not affecting enough customers to warrant them spending any resources to fix it. They suggested that we created an issue on UserVoice to see if it would gather enough votes for Microsoft to spend time on it. Yeah right, good luck...